# C# IPAddress from string

Tags: c#, string, ip-address

I need to define the IP address in the class `System.Net.IPAddress` but the method:

```
IPAddress ipaddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");  //127.0.0.1 as an example
```

doesn't work, is there another method?

How can I define the IP address?

Comment: There's no reason it shouldn't work. I suspect there's something else to the story here.

Comment: `define("doesn't work")`

Comment: That's not a **remote** server.

Comment: I've updated it here is the error : Assets/scripts/ServerClient.cs(14,47): error CS0426: The nested type `Parse' does not exist in the type `System.Net.IPAddress'

Comment: `if(CodeExample.Missing){HelpFromUs != Anything.Useful};`

Comment: Can you provide a complete code listing?

Comment: The code you posted cannot generate this compiler error, unless something is *seriously* wrong with your environment. Double-check that this is actually the code on line 14. Copy that code into a new solution, and try to compile that.

Comment: Describe the problem and how you solved it, or delete this question.

Comment: What fixed it? ...just so we know.

Comment: System.Net.IPAddress ipaddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

Comment: Ah. You have another `IPAddress` class somewhere in scope.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You've probably miss-typed something above that bit of code or created your own class called IPAddress. If you're using the .net one, that function should be available.

Have you tried using System.Net.IPAddress just in case?

```
System.Net.IPAddress ipaddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");  //127.0.0.1 as an example
```

[The docs on Microsoft's site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b2h863h(v=vs.110).aspx) have a complete example which works fine on my machine.

Comment: The link to the docs on Microsoft's site is now broken. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress(v=vs.110).aspx